# Pattern matching does not work as expected for Max

Tags: pattern-matching

```
h[1, x, y] /. h[b___] -> {b}
```

This code outputs {1,x,y}. But replacing h with Max (as below), it outputs {Max[1, x, y]}.

```
Max[1, x, y] /. Max[b___] -> {b}
```

Is this a bug for Mathematica?

Comment: This is not a bug. `Max[b___]`, since it has only one argument, evaluates to `b___`. The pattern `b___` matches pretty much anything, so it matches `Max[1,x,y]`. Since it found a match, it applies the rule, which just wraps the found expression in `List`.

Comment: This will do what I think you're expecting: `Max[1, x, y] /. Max -> List`. But since I don't see your actual context, I have no idea if that works for you in general.

Comment: Or just `Apply` `List`, i.e., `List@@h[1, x, y]` and `List@@Max[1, x, y]`

Comment: Or use `Max[1, x, y] /. HoldPattern@Max[b___] -> {b}`

Comment: I as confused. Why  ```b___``` matches ```Max[1,x,y]```, not just ```1,x,y```?

Comment: Because pattern-matching searches from left to right, so it _notices_ `Max[1,x,y]` as a whole before noticing the `1,x,y` inside.

Comment: Then why ```b___``` matches ```1,x,y``` in ```h[1,x,y]```, not ```h[1,x,y]```?

Comment: `b___` matches `h[1, x, y]`, too. `h[1, x, y] /. b___ -> aaaaa` outputs `aaaaa`.

Answer (score 9):

Pattern get evaluated like everything else. Therefore, when you write:

```
Max[b___]
```

this gets evaluated to (try it):

```
b___
```

So, what you actually match is:

```
Max[1, x, y] /. b___ -> {b}
```

and now it should be clear what is happening. The solution is to prevent the evaluation of the pattern by using "HoldPattern" like:

```
Max[1, x, y] /. HoldPattern[Max[b___]] -> {b}
(* {1, x, y} *)
```